# Oracle record type vs object

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, records

I have the below objects:

```
create type dep_rec_typ as object (did number, dnm varchar2(30));

create type emp_rec_type as object (eid number, enm varchar2(30));

create type emp_tab_typ as table of emp_rec_type;

create type dep_det as object ( dep_det dep_rec_typ         
                              , emp_det emp_tab_typ );
```

When I run the below code using the above objects the code run perfectly.

```
declare
    v_emp emp_rec_type;
    v_dep dep_rec_typ;
    c_dep_dt dep_det;
begin
    select did, dnm
    into v_dep
    where did = 100;

    select eid, enm
    bulk collect into v_emp
    where did = 100;

    select dep_det(v_dep, v_emp)
    into c_dep_dt               
    from   dual;

end;
```

but when I create the above objects at package level using RECORDS, I am facing error. 
Please let me know 
1.how I can write the same code without using the objects at database level.
2. Why I am facing error when I create RECORDS at package level.

Note: I can not change the structure of any of the objects.

Comment: what error you have facing? and how could you call it from package level?

Comment: Hi the error I face while using records is PLS-00597

Comment: how could you call it from package level? share your execution code.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the objects on package header as global variables using "index by" statement, then you can use it on your blocks the same way you would with the object type.

```
create or replace package test_types as

  -- Declare the types here
  type type_record is record ( p_id number
                             , p_name varchar2(100));
  type type_tab is table of type_record index by PLS_INTEGER;

  -- Declare the global variables here
  global_rec_type type_record;
  global_tab_type type_tab;

end;
```

then you can use it like this

```
begin

    test_types.global_rec_type.p_id   := 10;
    test_types.global_rec_type.p_name := 'Name in record';

  begin                
    select 1
         , 'Lucas' 
      bulk collect into test_types.global_tab_type
      from dual;
  end;

end;
```

Its not exacltly an object made of Records and Tables but it have the same results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Plain PL/SQL records don't have constructors. Therefore in your example, if `dep_det` is a record type then there is no such function as `dep_det()`. You would have to create one, perhaps naming it something like `new_dep_det`, which takes two arguments and returns a `dep_det`.